# Is this SQLi or XSS? (or both/neither)

Tags: xss, javascript, sql-injection

I'm trying to get the hang of SQLi and XSS, and I am starting to get the hang of it.

However: in my lab I made this:

```
ignore'"; UPDATE users SET name=<script>alert('Malicious activity')</script> WHERE name="John";--"
```

This seems to me to be an example of Stored XSS, since the script is entered into the DB, and is run when another user looks up "John".

But is this an example of Stored XSS? Or is this SQL injection, since I am injecting a script using a query? ... or neither?

Comment: It's not clear what context this is in.  Is this being put into a form field or HTTP request?  If so, it's both (as mentioned by CBHacking)

Answer (score 2):

*Assuming it works*, this is both, in two separate places.

It's SQL injection, quite straightforwardly. The attacker is breaking out of a SQL string, terminating the current query, and injecting their own query afterwards. It will only work on very poorly-written DB interaction code (and specific DB engines), but there's plenty of that out there.

The payload of the SQLi - again, *if and only if it works* - is stored XSS. It's a request that adds client-side content to persistent storage on the web app, such that the web app will return this content when some page(s) load, and the content will *presumably* get executed in the client. Of course, if the server properly output encodes the content from the DB before returning it, or the client injects the content into the DOM using `innerText` or similar, then of course the XSS attempt will fail. Of course, plenty of devs get that wrong, too.

Taken collectively, it's a pretty weird thing to do, though. You can do far more harm - possibly strictly more harm - by using a better SQLi payload, so creating stored XSS is a very weird thing to use SQLi for. On the flip side, if this sXSS attack works at all, then you probably don't need to use SQLi to do it (the exception would be if the site does have anti-XSS measures but they only validate input, rather than encoding output or rendering as text, which is a bad practice; input validation is the most error-prone method of preventing XSS although in some cases it's adequate).

Comment: Assuming this full string is being injected into a lower privileged operation (HTTP request / form field...).